# How can a .png file have a Query String?

Tags: php, html, png, query-string

I'm working on a site saved as php pages. 
An image tag has the following src value:

```
<img src="xxxxx.png?src=http://xxxx.com/xxx/xxx.png&amp;h=192&amp;w=334&amp;zc=1">
```

I've searched everywhere to try and decipher this. The first section `src="xxxx.png` is the location of the image in the local files. I am guessing the `?src=xxx` is a call to the server to resend an alternate image? This second image is the same image as the first, only slightly larger. Any guess as to what the developer is accomplishing?

On the same note, I'm not sure I understand the height and width in the same call...`h=192&amp;w=334&amp;zc=1`.

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Well, since it's a query string the browser will load up the first image just fine, then with some javascript you could decide whether the system can handle the larger image and load it in once a decision is reached. This would be a good system for mobile/desktop image loading as you load in the lower resolution (smaller file) image first.

Comment: Well, this looks like .htaccess file (my guess) is configured to read .png files as normal PHP files which pass in a get variable. Could you post the actual code?

Comment: Is xxxxxx.png a script by any chance?

Comment: you sure it's not xxxxxxxx.php? would make more sense to me, else maybe he does interpret png as normal php (as user1260028 is saying)

Comment: Adding stuff as a get parameter to a static artifact like an image is sometimes done to help with caching or web server directives. So image.png?[some timestamp here] is seen quite often.

Comment: You do not even need a htacces entry. You can create a DIRECTORY xxx.png containing an index,php (!!! Evil hack !!!)

Comment: @OliverA. i don't know if you are a genius or if this would cause so many problems with some server configurations... but nice idea